# Allowing alphanumeric and dot in scope

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

How can I allow only Alphanumeric characters and dots to a scope

```
<input type="text" ng-model="test" />
```

script

```
$scope.myFn = function(){
if($scope.test != ''){
alert("Please use only Alphanumeric characters or dots")
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    if (/[^a-zA-Z0-9\.]/.test($scope.test)) {
        alert("Please use only Alphanumeric characters or dots")
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

The better way is to define a `ng-pattern` on the html input element. This would not allow incorrect value to be set on model. I have not tested the regular expression pattern.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="test" ng-pattern="/[a-zA-Z0-9\.]*/"/>
```

Comment: The regexp needs to be anchored:`ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9\.]*$/"`